# I want to customize the display message when starting terminal on mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm an engineer and use a mac for work.
Is it possible to match case-insensitive path completion in terminal using the tab key?
Example: cd desk tab -> cd Desktop
If you know how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Execution environment
Tip:Apple M2
macOS:13.0

I tried the terminal command below, but nothing changed.

`zstyle ':completion:*:(cd|less):*' matcher 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'`

Sorry for my bad English。

Comment: Have you tried [this suggestion?](https://superuser.com/questions/1092033/how-can-i-make-zsh-tab-completion-fix-capitalization-errors-for-directories-and)

Comment: Just being curious: How is the **title** of the question related to the **content** of the question?